# Append a Parent to a Child Element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I need Help for append a Child element to a parent Element. This is my code.I need to put the $input inside the $temp.

Thanks

```
function CaixaPin(){

  var $temp;
  $temp = $("<div></div>");
  $temp.addClass("caixa");

  var $input;
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    $input = $("<div></div>");
    $input.addClass("caixaPin");
    $("body").append($input);
  }


  $("body").append($temp);

}

CaixaPin();
```

Comment: Just change $("body").append($input); to $temp.append($input); and everything should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Body` as well as `$temp` as well as `input` are DOM elements. You can append things to DOM elements, meaning  you will add some HTML inside the element you're appending to.

Since you're appending everything to body (i.e. `$("body").append()`), you will not succeed in getting a parent - child structure with regard to `$temp` and `$input`. Instead append `$input` to `$temp` after which you append `$temp` to `body`.

```
function CaixaPin(){

  var $parentElement;
  $parentElement = $("<div></div>");
  $parentElement.addClass("caixa");

  var $childElement;
  for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
    $childElement = $("<div></div>");
    $childElement.addClass("caixaPin");
    $parentElement.append($childElement);
  }


  $("body").append($parentElement);

}

CaixaPin();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can append to elements that are not already in the dom and are stored in variables like `$temp`

Change:

```
$("body").append($input);
```

To:

```
$temp.append($input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! :D

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate loop of `$input` after append `$temp`.

Try below example,

```js
function CaixaPin(){
    var $temp;
    $temp = $("<div>$temp</div>");
    $temp.addClass("caixa");

    $("body").append($temp);
    
    var $input;
    for(var i=0; i<4; i++){
        $input = $("<div>$input of "+i+"</div>");
        $input.addClass("caixaPin");
        $(".caixa").append($input);
    }
    console.log("Inspect your html code and check.");
}
CaixaPin();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Comment: Welcome always.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this

https://jsfiddle.net/zyjje3r8/1

```
<div class='parent'>
parent div - click to add child
</div>
<div class='parent'>
parent div - click to add child
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$(".parent").on("click",function(){
$(this).append("<p>child element</p>")
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help !! :D